# java ee7 interceptors vs callbacks

Tags: java, java-ee-7

What is the difference between Interceptors and Callbacks?
Can I use @AroundConstruct and @PostConstruct interchangeably, will they always be involve (more or less) the same time?

Comment: Time? That's certainly a wrong subject to consider as the overhead of either is negligible.

Comment: Are you asking about performance here, or the sequence of events?

Comment: Both, I would like to know what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the overhead of either is probably negligible, and not worth worrying about until you actually have a real problem to talk about.

As for the sequence of events (and other differences), the javadocs for [AroundConstruct](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/interceptor/AroundConstruct.html) and [PostConstruct](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) answer that.

`AroundConstruct` must be defined on an interceptor, and the real constructor is invoked after the last such interceptor calls the `proceed` method on the `InvocationContext`.  So these will technically run *before* the constructor, but you get control back after it runs (thus the name "`Around`"), so you can do post-processing as well.

`PostConstruct` *can* be use defined on an interceptor or on any void method with no parameters on the object itself.  It is invoked *after* the container has finished with dependency injection (thus the name "`Post`").